# Configuring Sbt for Play with babel transpiler

Tags: playframework, sbt, babeljs

I've spent a lot of time on this trying to solve one problem after another. I ended up with a problem with infinite loops of transpiling. I feel I'm close to the solution but I have some missing block.

When I run activator the transpiler generates new main.js and the system detects a new change. So it runs another transpile. It happens again and again infinitely.

Here is my build.sbt:

```
name := """angular-seed-play-java"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean, SbtWeb)

JsEngineKeys.engineType := JsEngineKeys.EngineType.Node
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "6.0.3",
  "org.webjars" % "angularjs" % "1.3.0-beta.2",
  "org.webjars.npm" % "systemjs" % "0.19.36",
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "3.1.0"
)

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

val browserifyOutputDir = settingKey[File]("Browserify output directory")
browserifyOutputDir := baseDirectory.value / "public" / "js"

excludeFilter in (Assets, JshintKeys.jshint) := "*.js"

sourceGenerators in Assets += task[Seq[File]] {
  val outputFile = browserifyOutputDir.value / "main.js"
  "browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ latest ] ] " + baseDirectory.value + "/public/js/main.jsx -o "+outputFile.getPath !;
  List(outputFile)
}

pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, digest, gzip)
```

I've added

```
excludeFilter in (Assets, JshintKeys.jshint) := "*.js"
```

line in order to prevent the default transpiler runnning. Also without it I'm getting another error.

Here is the line in my project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("io.teamscala.sbt" % "sbt-babeljs" % "1.0.3")
```

Honestly I've read half o sbt book but I steel don't feel comfortable with this tool.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your SBT file is looks like your input and output use the same directory. I suspect that this directory is in `sourceDirectories`. By updating a file in that directory it marks the task as dirty and does as you say - rebuilds it infinitely.

Typical sbt builds keep source and generated files separated. In a pure scala world generated source goes into `sourceManaged` typically under `target/`.

If I figure out anything more I'll update this answer.